# Public fixed-length Strings

Tags: string, class, vba, constraints

I am just summarizing info about implementing a *digital tree* [(Trie)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) in VBA. I am not asking how to do that so please do not post your solutions - my specific question regarding fixed-length Strings in class modules comes at the end of this post.

A `Trie` is all about efficiency and performance therefore most of other programming languages use a `Char` data type to represent members of `TrieNodes`. Since VBA does not have a `Char` datatype I was thinking about *faking* it and using a [fixed-length String](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/sizestring.htm) with 1 character.

- Note: I can come up with a work-around to this ie. use `Byte` and a simple function to convert between `Chr()` and `Asc()` or an Enum, or delcare as a `private str as String * 1` and take advantage of get/let properties but that's not the point. Stay tuned though because...

According to [`Public Statement` on Microsoft Help Page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/HV080557554.aspx) you can't declare a fixed-length String variable in class modules.

[image]

I can't find **any** reasonable explanation for this constrain.

Can anyone give some insight why such a restriction applies to fixed-length Strings in class modules in VBA?

Comment: This is all based on COM/OLE architecture so these restrictions exist because the semantics of a public type in a public class must be described for any possible consumer of the class, and VBA cannot do that for a fixed length string, its not a describable type (e.g. no analog in IDL/ODL) rather (I'd wager) it's a regular string with compiler generated guard code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VBA/VB6 runtime is heavily reliant on the COM system (oleaut32 et al) and this enforces some rules.

You can export a class flile between VB "stuff" but if you publish (or could theoretically publish) it as a COM object it must be able to describe a "fixed length string" in its interface description/type library so that say a C++ client can consume it.

A fixed length string is "special" because it has active behaviour, i.e. its not a dumb datatype, it behaves somewhat like a class; for example its always padded - if you assign to it it will have trailing spaces, in VBA the compiler adds generated code to get that behaviour. A C++ consumer would be unaware of the fixed-length nature of the string because the interface cant describe it/does not support a corresponding type (a String is a BSTR) which could lead to problems.

Strings are of type BSTR and like a byte array you would still lose the padding semantics if you used one of those instead.